# Windows multi-threading enforcing thread priority

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

What I'm expecting to happen:

Since the process affinity is restricted to a single core, all the threads of the current process have to compete for the execution time.

Since thread `a` has a higher priority than thread `b` and it never blocks, thread `b` is never executed.

What I'm seeing:

Thread `b` gets spuriously executed.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to enforce this execution logic with WinAPI?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI a_function(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while (true) {
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI b_function(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while (true) {
        cout << "b" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD affinityMask = 1u;
    BOOL res = SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), affinityMask);
    if (!res) {
        return -1;
    }

    HANDLE a_handle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, a_function, nullptr, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr);
    HANDLE b_handle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, b_function, nullptr, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr);

    SetThreadPriority(a_handle, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
    SetThreadPriority(b_handle, THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);

    ResumeThread(a_handle);
    ResumeThread(b_handle);

    WaitForSingleObject(a_handle, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
b
b
b
b
b
```

Note: I'm not using `ResumeThread()` / `SuspendThread()` because :

"The SuspendThread function is not intended to be used for thread synchronization because it does not control the point in the code at which the thread's execution is suspended." ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/suspending-thread-execution))

Comment: Does your system have only a single core?

Comment: @fredrik No, but I set the process affinity mask to use a single core.

Comment: *Since thread a has a higher priority than thread b and it never blocks, thread b is never executed.* not think that this is must be true. how and show your test

Comment: `while (true) {     }` is technically UB - check the generated code - it might have been removed (Infinite loop with no side-effects).  If this happened `a_function` would return immediately.

Comment: @RbMm That's my expectation, not what is happening, hence the question.

Comment: @RichardCritten Using a debugger, the `while (true)` loop never exits. Adding a no-op doesn't help either.

Comment: I think this could be the reason for what we are seeing - _"...The scheduler solves this problem by randomly boosting the priority of the ready threads..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-inversion  Thread `B` is getting a boost and when `A` reaches the end of it's time-slice thread `B` gets to run because of it's priority boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Priorities are not absolute. As soon as you use multiple threads, and all of the threads are in a runable state (that is, they are not suspended or waiting on a synchronization primitive), they *will* run sooner or later. Priorities only ensure that threads with a higher priority get scheduled with less latency / larger time slices, but not that they get scheduled exclusively before any other class of thread gets a shot.

The rationale is something quite similar to what you constructed: Spinlocks. If thread `a` was a consumer, and thread `b` was a producer, then never running `b` would send `a` into a deadlock. That problem is commonly known as a *Priority Inversion*, because `b` would technically have priority over `a` as `a` is waiting on `b`, but the configured priorities, and the non-use of kernel synchronization objects doesn't reflect this dependency.

That's not just a hypothetical scenario, but actually quite common. You could argue that you wouldn't notice on a multi-threaded system, but the rationale is once again that you can't risk breaking the software just by restricting it to a single CPU core, or because all cores get occupied by high priority threads.

Comment: [Priority inversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-inversion) is the result of contention. There is no contention in the code posted. Threads are not competing for a shared resource. Though it reads reasonable, I'm not convinced that this proposed answer is actually correct. Are you using a more general definition of *"Priority Inversion"*?

Comment: @IInspectable There is no priority inversion in the example in the question, but it's also impossible to prove for the scheduler that there isn't (given the primitives visible to the kernel). So randomly ignoring priorities is the only action the scheduler can take to avoid this problem class, which then leads to the observed effects.